# Is it not allowed to use "there, where S V"?

Tags: grammar

I want to express some unearthly, mysterious atmosphere of the place.

The original sentence is :

> The task can only be accomplished in a certain place, where...(defines the requirement of the place)

I want to write in this way : The task can only be accomplished there(now I learned that 'in there' is wrong) , where...

What I really want to ask is not whether it is grammatically correct or not(I still am grateful for answering this too, though), but whether it sounds too awkward that it fails to deliver what I want to speak.

Comment: The problem is "*in there*" usually means "*inside of there, an enclosed place*", and it would really work if the place was where "*the angels soar on silken wings*", because that place surely isn't enclosed. However, it *would* work if you dropped the "*in*": "*The task can only be accomplished there, where...*" (no *in*).

Comment: In fact, you don't even need anything in place of "in a certain place:" "The task can only be accomplished where ..." should work.

Comment: @DanBron Drop the *in,* also drop the *there.* Why not?

Comment: @Kris Yep, that works too, but I believe OP's literal objective is to use *there* (besides, double-reference to the place has a particular, poetic effect; it creates a mystical atmosphere).

Comment: Oh, you're really kind and helpful. Have a good day!

Comment: And yeah, the double-reference thing. Thanks for pointing out the effect of double-reference, of which even I was not really conscious... Thank you so much after all.

Comment: Does the place have a name? _in the grotto, where ..._.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding usage, please check the last paragraph of this answer to see if it fits your needs.

It is indeed grammatically correct to say "The task can only be accomplished in a certain place, where xxxxxx". This construction is an example of **[apposition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/apposition) with a [noun clause](http://www.pitt.edu/~atteberr/comp/0150/grammar/nounclauses.html)**.

It is not awkward in any way, either. It's fairly common in English for speakers to say things like "Do you remember that time, when we first met?".

Incidentally, the appositive doesn't actually define the requirement of the place- it is an object with the same properties as the original, perhaps in a more explanatory manner. For example, in the phrase "My brother, who works in the circus, is a very interesting person", the appositive, "who works in the circus", is a noun (this is why you can form sentences like "I want to meet who wrote this"). "Who works in the circus" isn't enough to actually *define* my brother, but it *does* provide additional information about my brother.

Answer (score 0):

Or - (for example:) "We must travel to the Magic Palace... The task can only be accomplished *there - where* the natural laws of the universe do not apply."

Answer (score -1):

No, "in there, where" doesn't work.

Try:

*The task can only be accomplished **in a place where** ...*

with no comma, making the "where" clause restrictive.

Simpler:

*The task can only be accomplished **where** ...*

E.g.

> The Handbook of Linguistics - Page 141 Mark Aronoff, ‎Janie
>   Rees-Miller - 2008
>
> However, certain types of field linguistics **can only be done where
>   there are** concentrations of speakers (as many as possible) located
>   as near as possible to where their ancestors lived.

Or, if you really want the comma

*The task can only be accomplished **in a certain place, a place where** ...*

Comment: Well, I know I can write that way. What I feel is that if I wrote that way, the sentence loses the feeling that I want to be delivered. I want the light pause, given by using of comma, that somehow makes me think it creates a bit more of aesthetic sense. Meh, maybe I'm not really familiar to English... :p It seems it make no difference at all except for myself.

Comment: See the update at the end.